# Writing Clang tools without compiling clang

Tags: c++, clang, llvm

I am not sure I understand this correctly, but this is my understanding:

In order to compile a tool using clang's code (such as a source to source translator), you have to get the clang source, make it and then link your code to clang's source.

Is my understanding correct, or is there a library that I could just download and link my code to that instead?

Answer (score 1):

There are pre-built binaries out there, if that is what you are asking?

Look under "Pre-Built Binaries":

http://releases.llvm.org/download.html